# Setting up EC2 with external DNS service provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, instance

There is an instance in EC and i have the public IP using elastic IP 54.244.XXX.XXX

When i'm setting up the configuration on the DNS it asks for the primary NS and the IP... So the IP is set up. And the NS?, i tried using the public DNS of the instance without results. The site is still unreachable.

I'm trying to set the data in the DNS provider. The provider is asking for the NS and the IP for the primary name server. This is for hosting a website.

I believe that i'm not explaining myself well. I have bought a domain at nic.cl, and i have my instance in ec2 configured with elastic IP. From here i have the domain and the ip of the instance. But when i try to configure the dns to point my instance they ask me for the NS and the IPs..

Some pointers from here?

Comment: Too few information. What exactly do you mean by "setting up configuration on the DNS"? And which system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are being asked to set NS, then you are not setting up DNS, instead you are providing name servers to your registrar.

If your registrar does not provide DNS, you can use Route53 for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting mixed up between DNS and your IP. Your IP (unless it's running a DNS server) is not what you need to be entering into these nameserver settings.

Your nameservers would look something like ns1.dnsdomain.com and ns2.dnsdomain.com - when someone loads your domain name, one of these two nameservers are queried and will return the IP of your EC instance.

So, that brings us on to what you can do. Well, I'd be suprised if your domain registrar (the people you registered your domain with) don't have some sort of default nameservers which you can use. From there, you should be able to create A records for www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com.

If your domain registrar doesn't provide this service, you can use something like [cloudns](http://www.cloudns.net/) - you need to sign up, create an entry for your domain and then use the nameservers they provide you.